# Find out value of environment variables being passed to container by docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm troubleshooting a service that's failing to start because of an environment variable issue. I'd like to check out what the environment variables look like from the inside of the container. Is there a command I can pass in my `docker-compose.yaml` so that instead of starting the service it prints the relevant environment variable to standard output and exits?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`docker-compose run rabbitmq env`

This will run `env` inside the `rabbitmq` service. `env` will print all environment variables (from the shell).

If the service is already running, you can do this instead, which will run `env` in a new shell in the existing container (which is faster since it does not need to spin up a new instance):

`docker-compose exec rabbitmq env`

Answer (score 1):

Get the container ID with [docker ps](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/).

Then execute a shell for the running rabbitmq container by running [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) command with the container id for your rabbitmq container.

Once you are on the rabbitmq container, you can echo out the value of any environment variable like you would on any other linux system. e.g. if you declared `ENV DEBUG=true` at image build time, then is should be able to retrieve that value with `echo $DEBUG` in the container. Furthermore, once you are in the container, you can poke around the log files for more investigation.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, first get the container ID with `docker ps`. When you have done that, view all the properties with `docker inspect <id>` and you will see something like:

```
[
    {
        ...
        "Config": {
            ...
            "Env": [
                "ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true",
                "DOTNET_VERSION=6.0.1",
                "ASPNET_VERSION=6.0.1",
                "Logging__Console__FormatterName=Json"
            ],
            ...
        }
    }
]
```